# Reading and setting property multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, instantiation, instance-variables

My project has 3 classes, and 2 threads. When I access a property on the class the thread is created from, I get the right value. The class I'm reading from starts a second thread. From this new thread I want to read the property from the second class.

When I set the value in class1 the value is 1, but the value in class3 is 0.

```
class test
{
    public void main()
    {
        Class2 cl = new Class2;
        thread th = new thread(new threadstart(a.start));
        th.start()

        cl.test=1;
    }
}

class Class2
{
    private int test;
    public int test
    {
        get { return test;}
        set {test = value;}
    }

    public void start()
    {
        Class3 cls = new Class3();
        thread th = new thread(new threadstart(cls.begin));
        th.start();
    }
}

class Class3
{
    public void begin()
    {
        Class2 cl = new Class2();
        MessageBox.show(cl.test.tostring());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to type `cl.start` instead of `a.start` in `test::main`

Answer (score 2):

You've got two separate instances of `Class2`. The instance created in `Class3` has no idea what the values are in the instance you created in `Class1`.

If you know you only want a single instance of the `test` property to deal with, you could make it static:

```
public static int Test { get; set; }
```

And then reference it using:

```
Class2.Test = 1;
```

As an aside, I'm not sure how this compiles since you've got a public property named "test" to access the private "test" variable in `Class2`. Typically, people name the private variable something like `_test` *(depends on your personal preference)*, or just omit the private variable altogether like I did above if your property is doing nothing other than accessing the private variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built in .NET libraries for managing threads. [Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

Follow some of the tutorials here. These objects make it much easier to deal with threads and wait for results. They even have thread-safe object available for you.

Thread-Safe Equivalants:

`Array,List` => `ConcurrencyBag<T>`

`Dictionary<K, T>` => `ConcurrentDictionary<K, T>`